# Define new scheme in the android textview with url

Tags: java, android, android-intent, textview

Hi I try to implement something like this , i have textview inside the listview and inside the textview i have string with word like ("look:") i made it look like a link with Linkify but i have to redirect this to my activity so that ("look:java") will call activity that will redirect and search the word java. How can i define new scheme that do the job , just asking how to define the new scheme other part just extra info.

Comment: The scheme tag is for the programming language.  Please remove it from this question.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to do it with something like:

```
<activity android:name="com.something.ActivityName">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <data android:scheme="look" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

see: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/data-element.html

Also, you might have to do "look://something" instead of "look:something"

Comment: i will definitly check that , here how it is (look : string here) clickable part is "string here" part not look part included , just make sure you get it right